SQLAlchemy: how to get table name from clause
>>> field = func.sum(MyModel.count)
>>> str(field)
'sum(my_model.count)'

I'd like to get table name 'my_model' via inspecting variable field

Inspect the field variable to extract the table.
from sqlalchemy.sql import expression

# Assuming `field` is already defined as in your example
table_name = field._element.table.name if isinstance(field, expression.Label) else field.table.name

print(table_name)


This code checks if the field is an instance of Label or a plain column expression and then extracts the table name accordingly.
